how to stop the FFmpeg process programmatically without using Ctrl + C?
const shell = require("shelljs");

const processShell = shell.exec(
  `ffmpeg -i "https://pull-hls-f16-va01.tiktokcdn.com/game/stream-2998228870023348312_or4/index.m3u8?expire=1728629296&session_id=000-2024092706481532076B1319E1100113F8&sign=1016b521d08053bc0ae8eddb0881b029" -movflags use_metadata_tags -map_metadata 0 -metadata title="Chill chill kiß║┐m k├¿o Warthunder" -metadata artist="bacgaucam" -metadata year="2024" -c copy "downloads/bacgaucam-927202491939.mp4" -n -stats -hide_banner -loglevel error`,
  { async: true }
);

setTimeout(() => {
  // processShell.kill();
  process.exit();
}, 20000);

my video only works when I use Ctrl+C to stop it. I’ve tried using process.exit(), .kill(pid, "SIGINT"), and the .kill() method from the shell.exec() ffmpeg() of fluent-ffmpeg or spawn() of child_process reference, but none of them work
If you want to test it directly, please message me to get a new live url in case it expires (https://t.me/ppnam15) or clone this:
https://github.com/loo-kuhs/tiktok-live-downloader
can anyone help? Thanks!

Maybe try providing signal in processShell.kill(), like 'SIGKILL'?

thanks, i tried but not work, process still run until i ctrl + c

I updated my answer to kill the proccess

'use strict';

const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const url = "https://LongURL/file.m3u8"

const ffmpeg_process = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', url, '-c', 'copy', './video.mp4'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] });

ffmpeg_process.on('spawn', () => {
    console.log('FFmpeg process started');
});

ffmpeg_process.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Failed to start FFmpeg process:', err);
});

ffmpeg_process.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
});

function stopFFmpeg() {
    if (ffmpeg_process && ffmpeg_process.stdin) {
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.write('q');
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.end();
        ffmpeg_process.on('close', () => {
            console.log('FFmpeg process stopped');
        });
    }
}

setTimeout(stopFFmpeg, 10000);


I tried and the process in the terminal stopped but the video still couldn't be viewed or deleted. I checked the task manager and saw that ffmpeg was still running.

The url of the video in your example is not valid if you open it in the browser HTTP ERROR 404. Try with an url that not expires. https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs exit(code)
Exits the current process with the given exit code.

If you want to test it directly, please message me to get a new live url in case it expires (https://t.me/ppnam15) or clone this: https://github.com/loo-kuhs/tiktok-live-downloader

kill -9 18228
Stop-Process: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '18228'.

I tried another way using taskkill, but the video still couldn't be played.

If you stop the FFmpeg process using Ctrl + C, Can the video be played?

yes, the video can always play if I use ctrl c

Why do you use the package ShellJS instead of rely in Node.js Child process?

This issue arises in the source code that I took from a Git repository to meet my company's requirements. If I don't kill the process through code, I see that ShellJS works great. I also tried using child_process, which provides more convenient events to manage the process. However, the video is almost unwatchable that way, so I still choose to use shelljs.

I will just now update my answer with a code using spawn that works right (At least in my tries)

it works   thank you so much, love you <3

Hope you can explain more details to me

Take a look to: Using stdout, stdin, and stderr in Node.js (https://blog.logrocket.com/using-stdout-stdin-stderr-node-js/)
stdout, stdin, and stderr are standard streams, which interconnect input and output communication channels between a program and its environment when the program executes.
Note: The { stdio:['pipe','pipe','pipe']} option passed to spawn means that the parent process' stdin, stdout, and stderr are independent of those of the child process.

I don't really understand the use of { stdio:['pipe','pipe','pipe']} in this task because I tried removing it and everything was fine.

Yes, you're absolutely right! The { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] } configuration is actually the default behavior for the spawn function in Node.js when no stdio option is provided. So, even if you remove it, the code will still function as expected.
